# React Hook - Converting from class to hooks - Ternary Operator

Tags: reactjs, class, ternary-operator, react-hooks

I'd like to change this to the hook format or function.

**CODE**

```
updateRoom(roomId){
  if (roomId === '') {
    this.setState({RoomId: '', Room: ''})
  } else {
  this.setState({RoomId: roomId.key, Room: roomId.name});
  }
 }
```

What am I missing in my ternary operator?

And would I have to change my function name to `useUpdateRoom` to represent a hook function?

**HOOK**

```
function UpdateRoom(roomId) {
  return '' ? setRoomId : Room
}

function App() {

  const [rooms, setRooms]   = useState('');
  const [roomId, setRoomId] = useState('');
  const [user, setUser]     = useState('');


return (
  <div className="app">
  <div className="room">
  {rooms.map((room, index) => (
    <Room key={index} index={index} room={room} />

  ))}
 </div>
 </div>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your ternary isn't evaluating roomId. I've also renamed the param to just 'id' for clarity. It should be:

```
function App() {
  const [rooms, setRooms]   = useState('');
  const [roomId, setRoomId] = useState('');
  const [user, setUser]     = useState('');

  function updateRoom(id) {
    return id === '' 
      ? setRoomId('')
      : setRoomId(id)
  }

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="room">
      {rooms.map((room, index) => (
        <Room key={index} index={index} room={room} />
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
  )
}
```

Also, you'll need to put the function inside App so it has access to the setRoomId.

Lastly, I can't see where you're calling it, but it would be something like:

```
<button onClick={() => updateRoom(some_id)}>Change Room</button>
```

Comment: it's also saying that `setRoomId is not defined`

Comment: should i define my destructured constants globally? or just place my function below the `App` function?

Comment: I've just updated how it could be done. I avoid doing globals where possible, having inside the component is fine.

Comment: it's giving me `rooms.map is not a function`

Comment: Your 'rooms' state is a string by default. If you change it to an array, you can use map: 
const [rooms, setRooms]   = useState([]);

Comment: If I wanted users to be able to add in whatever chatroom name they want, would I just add `const [rooms, setRooms] = useState(['']);`?

Comment: When you declare "const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([])", you are creating some state, and by using the empty array, you're giving that state a type (you can also include initial values within it, but an empty string isn't necessary).

To allow users to update the array with their own values, you'd need a separate input element (probably linked to it's own state), and perhaps when they click a 'Create Room' button, you'd have another function to update the 'rooms' state - which would then trigger a render, and your mapped rooms would reflect the new list.

Comment: gotcha, yeah ok, it'll probably be best to separate a chatroom list in a different file and import it or something.

Comment: Yep, I suspect you'll end up with a few different components. Whether you separate them into different files is up to you, whatever makes most sense.

Comment: also, any difference between using arrow functions vs function expressions for these hooks?

Comment: No difference - it's your preference. When writing React class components, arrow functions are useful as they automatically bind 'this', but that's irrelevant for hooks and stateless comps.